# FileNotFoundException + Writing a File to SD Card

Tags: android, file-io, sd-card

I am trying to download a file from the net and write it to the SD card. I have the WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE permission enabled. The code fails here:

```
OutputStream output = new FileOutputStream(filePath);

09-15 19:40:31.630: WARN/System.err(7933): java.io.FileNotFoundException: /sdcard/artoo/Customerv08.apk
09-15 19:40:31.630: WARN/System.err(7933):     at org.apache.harmony.luni.platform.OSFileSystem.open(OSFileSystem.java:231)
09-15 19:40:31.630: WARN/System.err(7933):     at java.io.FileOutputStream.<init>(FileOutputStream.java:96)
09-15 19:40:31.630: WARN/System.err(7933):     at java.io.FileOutputStream.<init>(FileOutputStream.java:169)
09-15 19:40:31.630: WARN/System.err(7933):     at java.io.FileOutputStream.<init>(FileOutputStream.java:147)
09-15 19:40:31.640: WARN/System.err(7933):     at com.artoo.settings.InstallerActivity$ProgressDialogAsyncTask.doInBackground(InstallerActivity.java:148)
09-15 19:40:31.640: WARN/System.err(7933):     at com.artoo.settings.InstallerActivity$ProgressDialogAsyncTask.doInBackground(InstallerActivity.java:1)
09-15 19:40:31.640: WARN/System.err(7933):     at android.os.AsyncTask$2.call(AsyncTask.java:185)
09-15 19:40:31.640: WARN/System.err(7933):     at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask$Sync.innerRun(FutureTask.java:256)
09-15 19:40:31.640: WARN/System.err(7933):     at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:122)
09-15 19:40:31.640: WARN/System.err(7933):     at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.runTask(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:648)
09-15 19:40:31.640: WARN/System.err(7933):     at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:673)
09-15 19:40:31.651: WARN/System.err(7933):     at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:1060)
09-15 19:40:31.670: WARN/InputManagerService(53): Window already focused, ignoring focus gain of: com.android.internal.view.IInputMethodClient$Stub$Proxy@43868480
```

I am trying to write the file and it doesn't exists from before. Any ideas on how to do this?

Comment: does the artoo directory exist?

Comment: Have you checked your SD Card and the file (via file explorer/browser)? You are sure the file is not there?

Comment: are you using `Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory()` to get the root of the external storage?

Comment: @All, sorry about the confusion. The file didn't exists and I thought the OutputStream would take care of it directly. I had to create the filePath & the file before using the OutputStream

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You are getting that error because the file specified cannot be opened or does not exist. It's simple as that.

I always create a file before and use a bufferedstream to write to it, ex :

```
File file = new File(path, name);
file.createNewFile();
BufferedOutputStream out = new BufferedOutputStream(new FileOutputStream(file), BUFFER);
```

Comment: In addition, I had to create the path as well: file_path.mkdirs()

Comment: The FileOutputStream is suppose to create the file if it doesn't exist. Of course, it should not create parent folders but still, the file should be created : "Constructs a new FileOutputStream that writes to path. The file will be truncated if it exists, and created if it doesn't exist." http://developer.android.com/reference/java/io/FileOutputStream.html#FileOutputStream%28java.lang.String%29. So this is a bug !

Answer (score 2):

check your permission in Manifest file, guy,

give your app the permission WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE

Comment: This is useful for me, I forget to add this permission in AndroidManifest.xml